Why does my Sensi thermostat shut down and reboot when calling for AC?
I have a Sensi smart touch thermostat. My home runs a dual transformer system with one 24v for heat and one 24v for cooling. I do not have any C wires for my thermostats. I jumped the G and Y wires at the AC air handler to create a constant 24v for the thermostat. I know I will no longer be able to run the blower motor separately now at the thermostat. The thermostat powers on completely.
However, when switched to cooling mode and the AC kicks on, the thermostat shuts off and reboots back to the home menu. I am not sure if the power drain from having the AC on is too much for the thermostat while sharing the blower wire. If so is there any way to remedy that? I see there is a device called a Fast Stat common maker. Will adding that at the AC air handler change anything?

If you jumped G-Y at the air handler, you now have an unused wire, formerly used for G.  THAT can be used as the C wire.  Connect it to C, and only C, at both ends.   Have you done that? Leave a note at both ends so people are not in future confused by the use of a green wire as C.   Make sure the A/C's R is connected to the thermostat's Rc and the thermostat's Rc/R jumper is removed.   The yellow wire should remain connected to Y at the thermostat and nothing should be connected to G.  This should work well, except for loss of independent fan control.

Yes I have wired like that and now using the G as the C at the thermostat. The only thing I'm not sure is moving the G to C at the air handler. The control board is all spiced wires instead of being connected directly to the board so I'm not sure how to move it to C. The thermostat powers up properly but when calling for AC it shuts off and reboots.

If the green wire is on C at the stat and still on G at the blower, that's definitely not going to work. You are forcing a 0V input to the thermostat when it tries to turn the system on.  If the blower doesn't have an obvious "C" terminal, you can find somewhere to connect the wire.  You can post a new picture of it showing all its wires and its transformer and its wiring diagram.  There are many similar questions here.

There's an official first-party C-wire extender for your thermostat, the Emerson/Sensi SA11 Thermostat Common Wire Kit. I'd do that to minimize variables.

Answering based on the question and subsequent comments.   Shorting Y/G t the blower, sacrificing independent control of the fan, frees up the green wire, formerly used for G so it can be used as C instead.
Your problem is caused because the green wire remains connected in a way that is shorting the thermostat's power input when it tries to turn on the A/C.
The green wire should be used as C.  Connected to C at the thermostat, and to C and nothing else at the blower.  If the blower has no obvious C terminal, it should be easy to find a place to connect it.  There are lots of similar questions here about that, or you can post a new question with appropriate photos.
Meanwhile, just disconnect the green wire from G at the blower.  The thermostat might work, a little, and unreliably.  IT won't reboot the way it's doing now.   If it works, don't rely on it ... finish the job ... but it's a first step.
Note: a C-wire extender, like the one you mentioned in your question, is cheap, and is a good idea.  Independent fan control is useful.  Your thermostat can make use of that to create better temperature balance in the house, and to reduce energy costs on mild days.  I do not recommend the "jumpered G/Y" approach at all.  This answer is just to pointedly solve your problem.
